# How to initialize a class property as an empty array in php extension development

Tags: php, php-extension

one can init an empty array in class in php like this:

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar = [];
}
```

but how can I do this in extension developed with c?

notice that the `$bar` property is not initialized in constructor.

I've already tried the `zend_declare_property` function, but I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0
```

PS: `[]` is the shortcut for `array()` in php5.4, and my question is about writing php extension (with c), not about php itself. I know my english is not good enough but if something I've written is hard to understand, please let me know.

Comment: declaring a empty array like that only works in php 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this..

```
protected $bar = array();
```